# Создание роутинга Django + React

Tags: django, reactjs, маршрутизация

Я сделал обычный роутинг на react :

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to='/'>App_zero</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='/app_one'>App_one</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='/app_two'>App_two</Link></li>
    </ul>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={App_zero}></Route>
      <Route exact path='/app_one' component={App_one}></Route>
      <Route exact path='/app_two' component={App_two}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
  </Router>
```

и он хорошо работал , но когда я использовал это в проекте , где я совместил React и Django возникли ошибки.Когда я начал переходить  по ссылкам все было нормально , но когда я обновил страницу(на которую перешел) или сделал какое-то действие , которые вызвало обновление страницы , то Django мне выдал ошибку , что такого url не существует.Я понял , что React и Django начали конфликтовать.Как сделать чтобы Django не выдавал ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Эта проблема возникла из-за того, что Вы не указали Django направлять роуты React'a на его роутер. Исправить можно таким образом:

Файл urls.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    ..., # тут все Ваши роуты
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    # вместо index.html может быть путь к вашему основному файлу
]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!Но у меня теперь бесконечно загружается страница и контента никого не показывает.